# Laravel: Where consult in a foreach loop not working

Tags: php, laravel

I dont know what am I doing wrong, I have a foreach loop and a where consult inside it and when I try to get the data through that object, it says that it's and non-object and I cant get the data.

```
public function actualizar_costo_promedio()
    {
        $empresas = Empresa::all();

        $anteriores_exist = 0;
        foreach ($empresas as $empresa) {

            $producto = $empresa->productos()->where('producto_nombre_id', 1)->first();
            $anteriores_exist += $producto->existencias;
        }
     }
```

If i do this, it gives me that error but if I change the where for only `$producto = $empresa->productos()->first();` it works

I've made other tests with `$empresa = Empresa::find(1);` and after do the consult  `$producto = $empresa->productos()->where('producto_nombre_id', 1)->first();` and also it works, so I don't understand what it's wrong

Comment: For start, you're not giving us line numbers and **exact error message**. That's what you're doing wrong. The second thing that you're doing wrong is doing this in PHP when you could be doing it using SQL only. You're having a problem with your perceived solution. It's also known as XY problem.

Comment: The error: PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object... 
Isn't that's why laravel's eloquent was made for? I dont know what you mean with your third point

Comment: So you think it's a good idea to load your entire table in PHP, then for each record issue a query, then increment a variable? Records grow. You do not know how many records you'll have. Their number is not known. The memory a PHP script has available **is known** and **is finite**. You're doing the task in a really, really bad way. You can use 1 query and ask MySQL (or whatever database you have) to give you the number you want. I won't bother mentioning, again, the line number. Your `$producto` is not an object, that's my guess (and probably correct one).

Comment: @N.B. Why would he do this in SQL if that is a reason for using the laravel framework? Why don't you try having less pride and try to help more?

Comment: @GoogleMac why would he do data manipulation and querying using a system designed for data manipulation and querying? I don't know, because it's the right tool for the job, because it's faster, because it's readable, because it uses less resources and will actually work. You *use the framework* to *obtain the result* by issuing the query which explains to RDBMS what **data** you want back. Do you even code?

Comment: @N.B. hahaha, yes, and I do it fluently. Along with the Laravel framework comes Eloquent. The purpose of this is to mask the SQL queries so it's not so choppy. You can write it out using PHP. Sure, one could argue that there is a little performance lost, but I say it allows for better-structured code, which means it's more easily maintained and scalable.

Comment: @N.B. Your point about doing this in SQL because that is what SQL is made for is like saying I should use Microsoft Word whenever I need to type up a document just because that is what is was made for. There are many ways to accomplish a task. Why confuse Christian by telling him he should write SQL when clearly Eloquent is what he is already using and is asking for help with? You are forcing your own opinions on people asking for help INSTEAD of trying to help them.

Comment: @GoogleMac sorry, but.. are you telling me that loading an entire table, whose size you can't know, in a PHP script - in order to find a SINGLE number after doing some summing is proper use of tools you have? Is that really what you're saying? If the answer is yes, then I doubt you code because that's just idiotic. I'm not confusing him, I'm simply letting another person know that there's another way, alternative to his initial thought, to obtain the result he's after. How long are you coding for? 3 days? Please, do your employer a favor and learn what SQL is for.

Comment: hahahaha! @N.B., I recommend researching [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#retrieving-models). It IS using SQL, but in a smarter, cleaner way. Also, I don't see the need for you to get personal- we are discussing code, not throwing out insults like 1st graders.

Comment: @GoogleMac you're right, no need to do this like 1st graders :) it's nothing personal, I'm just amazed how a grown up man, a programmer, a guy who even put in some effort in a github page makes a statement like you have. I know what you meant by it, I know you haven't read the question, and what I'm referring to is - is constructing an SQL query (using Eloquent) to get that number he's after. Reason I'm mentioning that is because he's doing `Empresa::all();` - and that will fail at some point when the table grows. So, you jumped to the conclusion, as I never said "ditch Laravel".

Comment: @N.B. I do see your point- I never was against that. I have been referring to your harsh criticism and telling him that he's doing it wrong because it's in PHP and not SQL (those are almost your exact words). And thanks for noticing my really old GitHub page that I got from a theme- haha.  I've been meaning to take that down. I'm not against your general point, just the deliverance. Think of me as the annoying, but hopefully somewhat helpful guy who loves working with newbies and other people with honest questions. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

So let me tell you what is wrong, this piece of code:

```
$empresas = Empresa::all();
```

returns a collection or an array of arrays.

Now when you are foreaching you are iterating over the `Empresa`, but then you are accessing a relationship

```
$empresa->productos()
```

which from the error I can tell that it's a one-to-many relationship since the error is happening because the relationship is returning you another collection and you are trying to access a property which throws the error.

But when you pick up the first item in collection you actually access the first array in that array containing all the arrays! Therefore this is working:

```
$producto = $empresa->productos()->where('producto_nombre_id', 1)->first();
```

So if you want to make it work you need another iteration inside the foreach, or as I can understand correctly you want to get the existing products foreach `Empresa` you could do:

```
$anteriores_exist = $empresas->map(function($row) {

    $products = $row->productos()->where('id', 1)->get();

    return $products->filter(function($row) {
        return $row->existencias;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi thx for the help, in your example code, it returned a collection with an array with collections haha, and these ones are empty if `$row->existencias` is = 0 which I dont need, also I cant access to my existencias attribute, I think is like the same result as if I was using an only foreach

Comment: And I fixed it with only using `$producto['existencias']`, why does this happen? if I debug it with dd($producto->existencias), i get the value, but if I try to save it in a variable it throws the error